# jQuery - select div at same level

Tags: jquery, class, html, select, parent

I want to select a specific div, when clicking on a button... The only issue is, it has to be the div of the buttonClicked's parent div... Sample:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="box">
     <h2>Langtidsparkering</h2>
     <div class="content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="listcontainer">
     <div class="list"> (THIS DIV SHOULD GET A CLASS "VISIBLE", WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED)
     </div>
     <div class="listbar">
       <button class="viewPrices" type="submit" title="Open">Se priser<span></span </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Code:

```
    $(".viewPrices").click(function () {
         $(".viewPrices").parents('.listaccordion .list').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Any suggestions ? :-)

Comment: Please add a demo fiddle.

Comment: Whops... take this one http://jsfiddle.net/unebune/n264v/1/

Comment: `$(this).closest('.listbar').prev()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it.

`.closest` will go up through the parents until it finds a match.  Then from that you can `.find` the target div that you are looking for.

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
     $(this).closest('.listcontainer').find('.list').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n264v/2/

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("div:eq(0)").toggleClass('visible');
```

This will select the parent div of the parent div where the button is.

Answer (score 3):

Edited your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n264v/3/

Also, the following code works too:

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
         $(".viewPrices").parent().siblings('.list').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

For this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
     <h2>Langtidsparkering</h2>
     <div class="content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="listcontainer">
     <div class="list"> (THIS DIV SHOULD GET A CLASS "VISIBLE", WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED)
     </div>
     <div class="listbar">
       <button class="viewPrices" type="submit" title="Open">Se priser<span></span </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Took the liberty to add the following css:

```
.list{
    display:none;
}
.visible{
    display:block !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle for the above sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4A7/)

Comment: Actually likes this one, but both divs with class .list opened when clicking the button... Hm.. weird..

Comment: This code will toggle EVERY element with the class "list"

Answer (score 1):

First of there is no div with the class "listaccordion" so you will never find a match.

You can use:

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
$(this).parent(".listbar").siblings(".list").toggleClass("visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
     $(this).closest('div').prev('div').toggleClass('visible');
});
```