# How to Effect the Selected Card's Part

Tags: html, jquery, css, show

I have lots of cards and I want to show some part of the card when value of input is chanced.
It's works but the problem is when value of input change then part of all cards are showing. I want to show only the selected card's part.

```js
$(".card input").focus(function() {
  $(".save-or-esc").css("display", "flex")
})
```

```css
.content-body.row {
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-body .card input,
.content-body .card textarea {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-body .card input:hover,
.content-body .card textarea:hover {
  border: 1px solid #e9e8ff;
}

.content-body .card input:focus,
.content-body .card textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #746AFB;
}

.content-body .card-cover {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card .card-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .save-or-esc {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: none;
}

.card .save-or-esc .btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .save-or-esc .btn .feather {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.esc-button:hover {
  color: #f20000;
}

.save-button:hover {
  color: #005CC8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-body row">

  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-title" type="text" name="content-title" value="About">
        <div class="save-or-esc">
          <button class="esc-button btn" type="button">esc</button>
          <button class="save-button btn" type="button">save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-title" type="text" name="content-title" value="About">
        <div class="save-or-esc">
          <button class="esc-button btn" type="button">esc</button>
          <button class="save-button btn" type="button">save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hey guys I added my project to snippet. I hope you can help me.
The problem is all ".save-or-esc" parts shows when i click the input. But i want only show the part of clicked card. Thanks.

Comment: give more code please. html

Comment: it doesn't matter to give html code. it's simple, when i change the value of input, some part going to show. but anyway, i'm adding html codes.

Comment: could you create a code snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to see your current code in action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it. Thanks to this [content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106006/jquery-select-div-at-same-level)

My jQuery Codes:

```
$(".card input").on("input", function() {   
  $(this).closest(".card").find(".save-or-esc").slideDown(500)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to detect whether the input is focused

```
  $('input').blur(function() { 
    //add code when input is not focused
    alert('blurred');
  })
  .focus(function() {
    //add code when input is focused
    alert('focused');
  });
```

Use this code to detect when input value is changed.

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: bro i'm not looking for something like this. i already did this event in different way. the thing i want is only the selected card's part have to show, not others part.

Comment: You mean you want to fadeOut or remove the other divs?

Comment: no. i mean only the selected card's part will show. not other's part show.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, then it only needs a minor change.
Instead of

```
$(".card input").focus(function() {
  $(".save-or-esc").css("display", "flex")
})
```

You should write:

```
$(".card input").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest(".save-or-esc").css("display", "flex")
})
```

Check the following example:

```js
$(".card input").focus(function() {
  $(".save-or-esc").parents('.card-cover ').css("display", "none")
  $(this).parents(".card-cover").css("display", "block")
  $(this).closest(".save-or-esc").css("display", "flex")
}).blur(function() {
$(".save-or-esc").parents('.card-cover ').css("display", "block")
})
```

```css
.content-body.row {
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-body .card input,
.content-body .card textarea {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-body .card input:hover,
.content-body .card textarea:hover {
  border: 1px solid #e9e8ff;
}

.content-body .card input:focus,
.content-body .card textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #746AFB;
}

.content-body .card-cover {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .content-body .card-cover {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card .card-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .save-or-esc {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: none;
}

.card .save-or-esc .btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .save-or-esc .btn .feather {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.esc-button:hover {
  color: #f20000;
}

.save-button:hover {
  color: #005CC8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content-body row">

  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-title" type="text" name="content-title" value="test1">
        <div class="save-or-esc">
          <button class="esc-button btn" type="button">esc</button>
          <button class="save-button btn" type="button">save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-title" type="text" name="content-title" value="test2">
        <div class="save-or-esc">
          <button class="esc-button btn" type="button">esc</button>
          <button class="save-button btn" type="button">save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working and i think you didn't understand me correctly. My problem is all parts shows. I want only focused card's part shows.

Comment: @SaintYusuf you mean that when you focus on one card that the others will `hide`?

Comment: @SaintYusuf check the edit please, i this this what you mean.

Comment: Oh my god... why nobody understands me? Don't hide other cards. I just want to show focused card's bottom part. But when i focus a card, all bottom parts show. I just need to see focused card's own bottom part.

Comment: For example: i click the first card, i need to see first card's own bottom part, not others bottom part.

Comment: @SaintYusuf the above example hides all cards that are not in focus. So if the content that you mean as `bottom part` in your card, exists inside the `HTML` of the `.card-cover` then it will only show. If the content is in a different element then match it with the focused input via some sort of `data` attribute.

Comment: @SaintYusuf it is crucial in questions to be clear for the reader in order want you want achieved. This question is easy we are just being lost in translation here, up to a point.